# display JSON in laravel blade

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Hey guys I'm using a rating system in my project and I'm trying to filter announcers according to their level

I used ajax for that

I get my data properly in the console( Array of objects)  but I'm wondering how can I loop through them and display them in my blade?

my jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.star-rating input[type=radio]').click(function() {
        var text = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({

            url: 'filterAnnouncer',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { text, },
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });            
    });
});
```

My Laravel Controller

```
public function handleFilterBagageAnnouncer(Request $request){
    $data = $request->text;
    $filter = BagageAnnouncement::whereHas(
        'announcement.user.profile.profileSetting',
        function ($q2) use ($data) {
            $q2->where('level',$data);
        }
    )->get();
    return json_decode($filter);
}
```

Comment: what type of data you are getting and what type you want to get show me the sample

Comment: I'm getting an array of objects containing the values coming from the query..
I want to display them in the blade..

Comment: can you share you blade code where you want to show this data?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue in your controller function code here.

```
return json_decode($filter);
```

this is wrong. `json_decode()` is to convert(decode) `json data to php objects`.
but you need to convert(encode) `php objects to json data`. so

```
return json_encode($filter);
```

now in your ajax success this how you can loop

```
success: function(data){

    // convert json data to js objects.
    // to make your we get js objects from json data.
    var dataArray = JSON.parse(data);

    dataArray.forEach(announcer => {

        // your code goes here.
        console.log(announcer);
    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer
how can I loop through " dataArray" in html to display the data?
I wanted to do something like foreach loop in laravel...

Comment: can't you see the forEach() function in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
success: function(data){

    // convert json data to js objects.
    // to make your we get js objects from json data.
    var dataArray = JSON.parse(data);
    items.forEach(function(item){
        $('selecter').append(item);
    });
}
```